# What is the good pattern for using numpy vectorization to operate on a large number of object states?

Tags: python, numpy, simulation

I am writing code for simulating the interaction of a large number (>500) of objects as (dicretized) time progresses. At each time instant, I want to use numpy to vectorize the update process, which involves calculations which are functions of every object's current states.

To make things complicated, at the start of every time instant, there may be addition or removal of the objects, so after a while the ID's may become discontinuous. This makes using a large numpy array to store everything in one place a bit hard to do; besides I want to preserve the current "object get attribute" style access of data for code readability.

I try to see if there is a way to use object hash to index the numpy arrays but so far there seem to be no such mechanism. I guess it boils down to the conflict of numpy requiring contiguous data storage in memory vs the dynamic nature of my problem data. I am currently working on maintaining a translation mechanism, essentially a two-way dictionary that converts the object hash to the corresponding numpy array index back and forth, but not sure if there is a better paradigm to do this kind of thing.

As an example, here is what I want to do written with an inefficient version:

```py
for t in range(0, MAX_TIME):
  all_bar = []
  for x in foos:
    all_bar.append(x.bar)
  all_baz = calc1(all_bar)
  for v in all_baz:
    x.baz = v
```

edit:
I know that you can modify the global large numpy array during runtime, but it would make the access of individual objects' attributes given there object handles cumbersome, since you need to figure out what its current index in the array is. I still would like to preserve the "x.baz" style access.

Comment: If your arrays contain 'objects' you aren't getting any significant numpy speed. You might as well be working with lists.  Fast numpy code requires numeric dtypes.

Comment: Have you considered using numpy masked arrays? (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html)
When an object dies, set it's mask value to True and future array operations will ignore it.
Echoing hpaulj's comment - if your "object" is just a numpy array itself, or multiple arrays, then this is fine. If your "object" contains none numeric primitive types - e.g. strings, functions, custom classes, then numpy may not be the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The object attributes I want to do calculations on are indeed of numerical types. I want to know the comment software paradigm for this sort of thing -- to vectorize the calculation when the data are associated with individual objects and may not be stored contiguously due to insertion/deletion.